# how to make a register page accept only one email address

Tags: python, django

I just want to know how to make a register page accept one email address

I have not tried anything yet

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

I want the register page to accept only one email address so it is used only once to register

Comment: sorry of the code being like that. I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: You can extend the django user model to use email address as the primary login field (i.e. instead of username). There are a number of tutorials for this - this is a good one: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html. For your purposes it would be option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is the code in Django to make a register page!!!
    models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Register(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Register'

    email = models.EmailField()

forms.py

from django import forms
from index.models import *
class Registerform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = '__all__'

views.py

from index import forms as formlocal
def register(request):
    form = formlocal.Registerform()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formlocal.Registerform(request.POST)
        some_var = request.POST.getlist('role')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
    return render(request,'index/register.html',{'form':form})

urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from index import views as ind
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', ind.register,name='joincoc'),
]

template - index/register.html

<form method="POST">
<div>
  {{ form.errors }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form.email}}
</div>
  {% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```